Is there a way of integrating motion from Framer-motion in Astro + React?
This is my code, the page renders perfectly but, the animation does not render.
NOTE: I have installed the required dependencies, such as framer-motion etc...
Dependencies:
"astro": "^4.4.0",
"axios": "^1.6.7",
"framer-motion": "^11.0.24",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0"
This is my code:
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

export default function Celebration() {
    return (
         ...
           <motion.h1 animate={{ x: 100 }} className="absolute box top-60 left-5 font-Black text-8xl text-white"> Some Text </motion.h1>
         ...
  )
};


[Edited]--This is my index.astro file:
---
import Celebration from '../components/todayCelebration.jsx';
import '../assets/fonts.css';
---

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <style>

            html,
            body {
                font-family: system-ui;
                margin: 0;
            }
            body {
                //padding: 2rem;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>
        <Celebration client:only="react"/>
      </main>
    </body>
</html>






Basically the result I'm expecting is a left to right animation after the page has fully loaded.

did you load it with <Celebration client:only />? btw. you may be interested in https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/

@mb21 Thanks for your response. I have modified my question. I have included my astro file in the question. The only issue I'm facing with this solution is that, when the page renders there's only a blank white screen. Your assistance would be much appreciated.
